# Drupal 7 Update Module Not Working

Tags: 7, updating

I just upgraded to Drupal 7 from Drupal 6. It appears I've finally gotten everything working, except the module updater isn't working; it can't update from a URL or a file. I also cannot install new modules.

I check the box next to the module to update and it appears that it's working, or downloading; it works for a few seconds, then it just reloads the updater page and nothing has changed. It is the same when I install a new module, entering the URL for the module, or choosing the file from my computer. Again, it appears to be working, but it just reloads the module install page.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a folder permissions problem.
Check to see that the user account that your web server is using to server web pages has write permissions in the 'sites/all/modules' folder.   Your webhost can help you with this.

Comment: The sites/all/modules folder has permissions of: drwxr-sr-x right now. I used chmod a+w to the directory also --- still does the same thing ...

Comment: ckeditor is one I'm trying to update and noticed that the files inside that folder only had read permission - I did a chmod a+w to all the files in the ckeditor folder and still does the same thing when I try to update ckeditor ...

Comment: I assume that this means I am giving "all" permission which would include the web server user?

Comment: unfortunately I am the web host...

Comment: Now have permssions for all/modules set to: drwxrwsrwx - still nothing ...

Comment: Same for me. This issue fixed?